# background-image border how to remove

Tags: css

I don't want a border around a background image yet there is a white thin line around it, how can I remove it.

I tried `border:0;` but didn't work. Here is what I have:

```
td.header
{
    background-color: #003;
    background-image: url(header2.jpg);
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 162px;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

What should I put into this to not have it show?

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle with an example? It's hard to tell what's going on here.

Comment: I would check the styling on the table and tr.

Comment: Have you got a URL, or some HTML etc for us to check? The css you provided looks fine so we need to investigate deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this:

```
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe `border: none;` works instead?

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-properties

Comment: Please, don't link to `w3school`. It is full of inacurate or simply wrong information. See http://w3fools.com/ for details.

Comment: Of course. I now searched the W3-site to find a similar list of the possible values and pasted that link instead.